# list.clear() is calling list.selectionchanged event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am developing a Windows Phone app. There is a list which has to be cleared once a list item is selected from it.
I used `Clear()`, but it's giving me some exception.
Is `list.Clear()` calling `list.SelectionChanged` event internally?
How to solve this problem?

Comment: I suspect that if an item in the list is selected when you clear the list that item will become unselected, raising the SelectionChanged event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try detaching/attaching event

```
list.SelectionChanged -= yourevent;

list.Clear();

list.SelectionChanged += yourevent;
```

Answer (score 1):

I will simply suggest to make changes to your SelectionChanged event to keep things in Sync.

```
private void SelectionChanged_Event()
{
    if(!list.Any()) // Or any similar check to see if it contains anything
        return;

    // Then goes your rest of the code.
}
```

It should avoid any exception you are getting. However, you should have mentioned the exception so that we can analyze it further.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to your mobile environment, but it should be the same.

Set a Break on the `selectionchanged` event, and see if it does break into the event. My guess is that you are right and that it does trigger the `selectionchanged` event.

Write code in the `selectionchanged` event to check for the number of selected items, if none (I.e. we are not actively selecting anything in the list), exit the function.

In vb.net it would be:

`If mylist.selecteditems.count = 0 then exit **sub/function**` <- whichever applies